# Symbolic perturbation expansion for quantum mechanics using Hellmann-Feynman derivaties

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, physics

I am interested in some quantum mechanical perturbation expansion for energies. Actually I want to implement [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#Second-order_and_higher_corrections) terms $E_n^{(k)}$. [As is stated below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#Correction_of_energy_and_state) one can do that using CAS. I would be interested how to implement this in Mathematica. In particular I am working on [this system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465459/perturbation-theory-development-for-the-ground-state-of-the-qm-particle-in-the-b).

I could imagine there are even some codes around in the net or published, since these are very common procedures in particle physics.

I am pretty much Mathematica beginner and I yet have no concrete idea how to do that.

I could imagine one could go for a two-step procedure first to derive the symbolic terms e.g. $$E_n^{(2)} = \frac{|V_{nk_2}|^2}{E_{nk_2}}$$ then one generates the explicit forms like

```
E[n,2]=Sum[Integrate[psi[n,x] V[x] psi[k2,x],{x,0,π}],{k2,1,Infinity}]/(E[n,0]-E[k2,0]
```

Which would be the exact correspondence of the symbolic term from above. On a more concrete level my problem is a very simple case, where I get on an explicit level

```
Integrate[psi[n,x] V[x] psi[k2,x],{x,0,π}],{k2,1,Infinity}] = v0 2/π Sin[n π/2] Sin[k2 π/2]
```

and

```
E[k2,0]=k2^2
```

But I am basically clueless at the moment how to exactly do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So the first part of the question is basically a physical one:

How to generate the symbolic representations of the QM energy perturbation expansion in Mathematica? I still want to pose it here, since I suppose that this has been already implemented quite often by someone in Mathematica. This is even mentioned in the Wikipedia page:

> "Both energy derivatives and state derivatives will be involved in
>   deduction. Whenever a state derivative is encountered, resolve it by
>   inserting the complete set of basis, then the Hellmann-Feynman theorem
>   is applicable. Because differentiation can be calculated
>   systematically, the series expansion approach to the perturbative
>   corrections can be coded on computers with symbolic processing
>   software like Mathematica. "

The second part of the question would be, how one could implement the actual expressions

```
E[n,2]=Sum[Integrate[psi[n,x] V[x] psi[k2,x],{x,0,π}],{k2,1,Infinity}]/(E[n,0]-E[k2,0]
```

given the symbolic terms:

$$E_n^{(2)} = \frac{|V_{nk_2}|^2}{E_{nk_2}}$$

Comment: May you be more specific as to your desired output? Just as a heads up, some of your links simply go to the top of the Wikipedia page, rather than the specific area which I guess you want to focus on. Are you trying to focus on the second and third energy corrections, symbolically as is described in the Wiki page? It seems like one could easily recreate these terms.  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#/Second-order_and_higher_corrections

Comment: Hi @Brad thanks for the in interest and the hint. Could it be that the links open differently on different system? In my system I end exactly were your link points to as well (however with the difference that it does so in the primary window without opening a second tab :-( so I am really confused now what to do. Very specifially I want the expressions in the yellow field (hope its yellow on everyones browser).

Comment: @Rudi_Bimbaum - I don't think so, since I used the hyperlinks in the Wiki page to direct you to the specific subsection I thought you were needed. If you follow my link above, I don't know if that big list of expressions for E is what you're looking for. If you just wanted to symbolically 
but automatically recreate the series of expressions for E in terms of the V's then that certainly seems doable. I'm simply unclear as to what you need; in your yellow box, you seem to want to explicitly calculate the separate values. Do you have the expressions for V[x] and all of the Psi as well?

Comment: @Brad: I have E and V as well they are very simple: $$E_{jk} = j^2 - k^2$$ and $$V_{ij}=sin(i π/2)sin(j π/2)$$. So I most strongly desire the final Sum[ ...] expressions, but I would also be very very happy about the symbolic expressions, which are exactly what you are referring to (big list of expressions for E).

Comment: What is to stop you simply defining something like `E[j_,k_]:=E0*(j^2-k^2)` and `V[i_,j_]:= Sin[i* Pi/2]*Sin[j *Pi/2]`, and then substituting them into your general formula? (I am unclear what the modulus achieves in this case, and also what the general formula to actually calculate for E is). Note that subscripts in real applications can be converted to arguments in functions for MMA.

Comment: That boils down to copying all the terms from the WP page and then I don't have access to higher than 5th order. So it would be good 1) to be able to generate the symbolic terms automatically and 2. to be able to translate them into expressions that can be evaluated.

Comment: So this is essentially two separate problems that you have, where only one of which is more of an implementation problem. Based on a cursory read of the Wikipedia page and your other Physics post, you're unclear as to what the general formula is and how it's generated; that's not an issue which most would deal with simply by lacking a knowledge of the relevant physics. 


I think that if you need to identity exactly WHAT the general formula is, i.e how one would theoretically generate all of these corrections, then you could then come back and ask us how to actually implement it in MMA.